# Enable Left - Right Scrolling On Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, viewport, meta

I have a website, which has an on screen width of around 800 pixels. Now I don't want to change that as I am perfectly happy with it as it is, however, the problem I'm getting is that mobile users aren't able to scroll to the right, so they obviously can't see the rest of the content. As far as I was aware from previous sites that I've built, the scrolling is a default feature if the site is larger than the screen, so what's the problem here?

I have this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5">
```

Which I suspect may be the problem? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Your meta tag looks fine. Without seeing your page I can't say for sure what's wrong. I would make sure you don't have overflow-x: hidden on your <html> or <body> tags.

Comment: Thanks David. I had `overflow-y: scroll;` in my CSS which I suspect is the culprit. However, I've decided to re-build my website to be mobile friendly, so hopefully this won't be an issue again.